# Retrieve the index of the first element using a predicate

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to change the legacy C-style code by using stl:

```
for (posEmptyItem = startAt; strlen(collection[posEmptyItem]) > 10; posEmptyItem++) {}
std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;
```

This code seems a bit hard to read. Anyway to do better?

```
auto it = std::find_if(collection + startAt, 
                       collection + COLLECTION_SIZE, 
                       [](const char* line) { return strlen(line) <= 10; });
int idx = std::distance(collection, it);
```

Below a complete example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#define COLLECTION_SIZE      250

int main()
{
    const char* collection[COLLECTION_SIZE]{ "time11,time2,time3",
                                       "time12,time2,time3",
                                       "time13,time2,time3",
                                       "time14,time2,time3",
                                       "time15,time2,time3",
                                       "x\n", 
                                       "" };
    auto startAt = 2;
    int posEmptyItem;

    // legacy code
    for (posEmptyItem = startAt; strlen(collection[posEmptyItem]) > 10; posEmptyItem++) {}
    std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;

    // replace the loop to search an index by calling to standard library
    auto it = std::find_if(collection + startAt, 
                           collection + COLLECTION_SIZE, 
                           [](const char* line) { return strlen(line) <= 10; });
    posEmptyItem = std::distance(collection, it); 
    std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"This code seems a bit hard to read."_ Why do you believe it's hard to read actually.

Comment: To compute the offset from an iterator looks stange to me.

Comment: There's nothing weird about using `std::distance` (I don't get where you did getting `std::dist` from. Maybe a MSVC specific typedef??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *"easier readability"* you could extern the lambda expression form the `find_if()`:

```
auto pred = [](const char* line) { return strlen(line) <= 10; };
auto it = std::find_if(collection + startAt, 
                       collection + COLLECTION_SIZE,
                       pred);
```

Also make use of `std::begin()` and `std::end()`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(collection) + startAt, 
                       std::end(collection),
                       pred);
```

At least (but probably not last), don't use raw arrays. Rather change `collection` to a `std::array`:

```
std::array<const char*,COLLECTION_SIZE> collection 
    { "time11,time2,time3"
    , "time12,time2,time3"
    , "time13,time2,time3"
    , "time14,time2,time3"
    , "time15,time2,time3"
    , "x\n"
    , "" 
    };
// Note my formatting style above, which makes it easier to extend the array
```

Here's the fully refactored code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

const size_t COLLECTION_SIZE = 250; // rather use a const variable than a macro

int main()
{
    std::array<const char*,COLLECTION_SIZE> collection
        { "time11,time2,time3"
        , "time12,time2,time3"
        , "time13,time2,time3"
        , "time14,time2,time3"
        , "time15,time2,time3"
        , "x\n"
        , "" 
    };

    size_t startAt = 2; // care about the correct type. auto would leave you with int

    // replace the loop to search an index by calling to standard library
    auto pred = [](const char* line) { return strlen(line) <= 10; };
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(collection) + startAt, 
                           std::end(collection), 
                           pred);
    auto posEmptyItem = std::distance(std::begin(collection), it);
    std::cout << posEmptyItem << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de161f2fece18c0e)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am learning the standard library and want to be check that my code is ok.

Comment: @LessWhite if you find the answer helpful you can upvote it ;-)

Comment: I don't think that `std::array` is a good substitute. No type traits work on it, even (ironically) `std::is_array`.

Comment: @Incomputable Feel free to make a better proposal for that particular case.